# Python Constants for a file path

Tags: python, python-3.x, constants

I need a constant for a file(database) path, as a base_directory.  I know there are no real constants in python.

I set this way:

```
base_dir = (os.getcwd().rsplit('\\', 2)[0],)
```

I need this value in multiple files, in different directories/folders levels/depths.  So I created a file with variables and I import the file where is needed.

The problem is that the `base_dir` is not calculated based were is the location(path) of the imported file, but based on the location of the current file.

So I have different paths based on the path depth.

I can change every time the `base_dir` to adapt to the new path, but I need to repeat not only the var declaration but a lot of related code for every file.

How can this be fixed, simulating a constant for a path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use [os.getcwd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path.getcwd). Get your constants file path with [os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

```
file_abs_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

And build path to database file with [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
database_path = os.path.join(file_abs_path, '..', 'path', 'to', 'db)
```

Then import constants and access `constants.database_path`.